# ValueError: substring not found when refactoring PySpark to work with snowpark

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build on the help I've received from SO members when refactoring PySpark code to snowflake.

Can someone take a look at the following snowpark python code and let me know why I'm getting invalid syntax error:

[image]

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

def registerDelta(session: snowpark.Session,regName, stage, filePath):
      
  pos = regName.index(".")
  if pos > 0:
    dbName = stage + regName[0:pos]
  else:
    dbName = stage
  
  try:
    crtdb = f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {dbName}"
    session.sql(crtdb)
    print(f"{stage} - Database created")
  except:
    print("Create Database Failed")
  
  try:
    SQL = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {stage}{regName} USING DELTA LOCATION '{filePath}'"
    session.sql(SQL)
    print(f"{stage}{regName} - Table created")
  except:
    print("Create Table Failed")

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    return registerDelta(session, 'test1', 'test2', 'test3')
```

I've got feeling this will highlight my lack of Python coding knowledge.

Anyway, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is purely based on code and it is not specific to Snowpark.

```
pos = regName.index(".")  # when string is not found it raises an error
if pos > 0:
  dbName = stage + regName[0:pos]
else:
  dbName = stage
```

> *I'm getting invalid syntax error:*
>
> *ValueError: substring not found*

This error is not a syntax error but a runtime error due to provided input and it is correct behavior.

---

[Python str.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index)

> ```
> str.index(sub[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Like find(), but **raise ValueError when the substring is not found.**

[Python str.find()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

> ```
> str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
> ```
>
> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. **Return -1 if sub is not found.**